# Can you recommend an operational scheduling/workflow management tool?

Tags: scheduling

We have a lot of scheduled jobs that do a variety of things-- moving logs around, ingesting and cooking them, fetching data from external sources, building reports, etc.  Some of it happens hourly, some of it daily, and there are lots of dependencies between various tasks.  We manage it all with an operations workflow tool that is nearly adequate in theory, but often falls short or falls on its face in practice.  Everything is linux-based.

It seems like this should be a fairly well solved problem.  Are there any good open source or inexpensive commercial systems that can handle this well?

Comment: Are you hell bent on staying MS free? Project is a great app.

Comment: I take it you are looking for something along the lines of AutoSys batch scheduling, or the Mecury ITG workflow management suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at JobScheduler - http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/  It's free/opensource and very robust.  I am currently in the process of implementing this here at work.  It's very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

eGroupware is an awesome app.  Open-source, able to use multiple email clients, even used by mobile phones.  www.egroupware.org

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I asked  my question anonymously. Silly me. JobScheduler looks very much like what I want-- in fact, it looks to be very similar to what we're using now, though hopefully with fewer annoying bugs.